# at c(x)% "where x is a numerical figure", what does that c mean?

Tags: c

When i read financial news, sometimes, there is cX% (where X is a number).

Below are few examples:
1. "improving to c4% on a proforma basis"
2. "market share is now c6% of the ..."

What does that c represent for? Does it mean "Compound Annual Growth Rate"? or "closed to"?

Answer (score 2):

It stand for "Circa", from Latin. It means "approximately".

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circa